# What happens when sql server is cascading updates and I cancel operation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I update a value on a table where the column cascades updates to many other tables (and the other tables have foreign keys that enforce referential integrity on that column) and I cancel the operation?  Is the whole operation treated as a transaction and rolled back?  I'm cancelling from Sql Management Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. That is what [A(tomicity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) in ACID is all about

Comment: So if I don't explicitly wrap a bunch of statements in a transaction, SQL server itself implicitly wraps the statements (individually) in a transaction?  And the cascading/referential integrity, although it decomposes into multiple updates, is treated as a single transaction?

Comment: @SFun28: yes, unless you have explicit transactions, then each SQL statement in itself is an implicit transaction

Comment: A single statement that is cancelled is treated atomically even if it causes other underlying operations. A set of statements you've issued, without transaction context? Not a chance. You can test this easily: `INSERT ... ; WAITFOR DELAY '00:20:00';` then hit cancel after a minute. Check the table; your `INSERT` happened.